# Efficient negation of subdiagonal values of a 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

How would one efficiently negate the subdiagonal entries of a 2d numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [numpy.tril_indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to compute the indices of the subdiagonal entries, considering a diagonal offset of `k = -1`, and negate them with a mask, for instance:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)

>>> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15]])

idx_low_tri = np.tril_indices(a.shape[0], k=-1)
a[idx_low_tri] = -a[idx_low_tri]

>>> array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
           [ -4,   5,   6,   7],
           [ -8,  -9,  10,  11],
           [-12, -13, -14,  15]])
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: amazing. of course there's a function for generating indices like this... just didn't know about it. thanks!

Comment: question about this solution: is `a[idx_low_tri] = -a[idx_low_tri]` faster than multiplying by a matrix with 1s and negative 1s in those indices?

Comment: I will guess that only masking half the entries is faster than performing scalar multiplication on every entries of `a`...